# Getting product_id in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm having trouble showing the ID of the product that I have in the cart, to perform a verification at the time of shipping.

I have the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'c7_hide_free_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function c7_hide_free_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
    echo $in_cart = false;
    global $woocommerce;
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $state = $woocommerce->customer->get_billing_state();
    $city = explode(' - ', $woocommerce->customer->get_billing_city());
    $distrito = '';
    if (count($city) > 1) {
        $distrito = $city[1];
    }
    if ($state != 'LMA' || 
        !in_array($distrito, ['Surquillo'])
    ) {
        unset( $rates['SD'] );
        unset( $rates['ND'] );
    }
    if ($state == 'LMA' &&
        in_array($distrito, ['Chorrillos'])
    ) {
      $rates['flat_rate:7']->cost += 0; // 7.5
      $rates['flat_rate:7']->label = 'De 1 a 2 dias';
    } else if ($state == 'LMA' && $product == '6721' &&
        in_array($distrito, ['Chaclacayo'])
    ) {
     $rates['flat_rate:7']->cost += 9.5; // 17.50
     $rates['flat_rate:7']->label = 'De 2 a 3';
    //Fin Prueba
    } else if ($state == 'LMA' &&
        in_array($distrito, [])
    ){
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:7'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

I am trying to get Product ID: 6721 to have a different shipping price than other products. That is, if I put it in the cart and I am about to buy a product, eg "Chair", it has a different shipping price than other products. I am trying to do it by code since it is structured for those districts in code.

Chorrillos District has a different shipping price for all products, on the other hand, the Chaclacayo District has another price only if the shipment is with ID 6721, but it does not let me, it does not change the price of the shipment and only shows the default shipment when it should to show 17.50. Any way to verify the product ID when buying? I already appreciate any help.